# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python

Here is my main file code

```
import moduleA as moduleA
import os

filename1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'script01.txt') 
filename2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'script02.txt') 
myList1 = moduleA.get_file(filename1)
myList2 = moduleA.get_file(filename2)
```

Here is my moduleA code

```
def get_file(filename):
    myList = []
    with open (filename) as filename:
        for line in filename:
            myList.append(line)
    return myList
```

I got an error saying that in get_file with open (filename) as filename:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I have checked that `type(filename1)` is string. I don't know where did I get wrong

Comment: Why do you use the same variable name `filename` twice? That's just asking for trouble, and might be the source of your error.

Comment: post the entire stack trace